# Cisco vpn client over squid

Tags: vpn, squid, firewalld

I have installed squid server like transparent proxy(in subnet 192.168.1.x). All users use squid to access to the internet from subnet 192.168.2.x. From user subnet I want connect via Cisco vpn client to VPN. As I read from internet, squid can't work with non http traffic. How I can connect to VPN bypassing squid?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by adding in firewalld -masquerade option

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade --permanent
```